# scheduling background tasks in succession

Tags: scheduling

I've got three SAS programs to run in the background over a weekend. The three programs output information into files of the same names, so I'll need to remove these output files after the first program finishes and before the second program starts, as well as after the second program finishes and before the third program starts. Obviously the simplest way to get around this issue is to alter each of the programs in such a way that the output filenames are different, but that wouldn't help me learn how to use Unix. So this is what I've got so far:

```
# Begin by running the first SAS program in the background.
sas program1.sas & | at 5:00 PM JAN 11

# I'd like to wait until the first program finishes to remove
# the output files and run the second program.
wait ???
rm file1.sas7bdat file2.sas7bdat file3.sas7bdat file4.sas7bdat file5.sas7bdat
sas program2.sas & | at 5:00 PM JAN 12

# And now I repeat.
wait ???
rm file1.sas7bdat file2.sas7bdat file3.sas7bdat file4.sas7bdat file5.sas7bdat
sas program3.sas & | at 5:00 PM JAN 13
```

I set each program to run at the same time on consecutive days for two reasons: (1) I know the previous program will finish within 24 hours, and (2) I am assuming the load on the server will be similar at the same time on consecutive days. Ideally I could somehow grab the process ID for the first program and pass it to the first `wait` command, and similarly for the second program and `wait` command. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I am more interested in a general solution for determining a process ID and passing it to the `wait` command than this specific situation.

Comment: Run them in a different directory?

Comment: @jordanm That's definitely an option, though that's really too problem specific. I provided the context for my problem because that's good practice and respectful to the community. However, my statement about somehow grabbing the process ID and passing it to the `wait` command is what I'm actually interested in answering.

Comment: @jordanm And now that I'm re-reading my post, I realize I started off with "My main problem ..." and didn't actually mention what I'm interested in until the end, so I'll edit the post.

Comment: Why dont you write a script this way: `sas prg1; rm tmpfiles; sas prg2; rm tmpfiles; sas prg3`? I'm not sure I understood your aims.

Comment: In bash you can use $! for getting last background job. But your scipt-example is not bash, right?

Comment: @dchirikov That's... surprisingly simple. By removing the ampersand from the `sas ... &` statements, the process will still run in the background and later commands won't execute until prior ones and background processes have completed? No, this is not bash.

Comment: @dchirikov It appears that by removing the ampersands, the sas programs no longer run in the background.

Comment: So do you need the unix command for determining a pid of a process? In general `ps -ef | grep sas`. But it is quite bad solution. Parent process must know all child PIDs it started

Comment: @dchirikov That's currently how I'm looking up the process IDs. I'd like to pass the process ID as an argument to the `wait` command as part of my script. The question is: If possible, how can I write a statement to grab the process ID and pass it as an argument to the `wait` command?

Comment: But `wait` is bash-built-in command. If you dont use bash you cannot use wait.

Comment: @dchirikov `wait` is part of POSIX shell, not just bash. See [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/wait.html)

Comment: Which posix shell supports `& |`?

Comment: @dchirikov I just assumed that was an error on OP's part, that it should be `echo 'sas program1.sas &' | at 5:00 PM JAN 11`, which appears much more valid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're using at for something its not supposed to be used for, really. You also have two conflicting goals: "run program 2 after program 1" and "run program 2 at 5pm jan 12".

One part of your problem is simple to solve: at allows multiple commands. So, instead of just using `at` to schedule the `sas` script, you can put the `rm` in the job as well.

```shell
at 5:00 PM JAN 11 <<EOJ
sas program1.sas
rm file1.sas7bdat file2.sas7bdat file3.sas7bdat file4.sas7bdat file5.sas7bdat
EOJ
```

There is no reason for the `&` in the `sas` line; `at` always runs jobs "in the background".

Next, you must figure how you want to solve the conflict mentioned earlier. In particular, if the Jan. 11 job hasn't finished 24 hours later (by 5pm Jan. 12). There are a couple of ways to go about it:

- It isn't really the Jan 12 job. It should run as soon as program1.sas finishes. In which case, just make it part of the first job above, just like the `rm`.
- This will never happen. If it does, you'll fix it manually. In which case, just schedule it like the one above.
- It needs to wait. In which case, you could either schedule it at the end of the first at job, or use a lock file, or calculate the appropriate amount of time to sleep (or use `sleepenh`, if available, to avoid doing the calculation yourself).

Comment: (+1) for a nice answer that points out logical flaws.

Answer (score 2):

So what you have and want to do basically boils down to the following.

```
command1 &
wait <on command1>
sleep <until specified time>

command2 &
wait <on command2>
sleep <until specified time>

...
```

In this case, removing the backgrounding (`&`) as well as the `wait` and `sleep` will cause the commands to execute in sequence. This, however, will make them execute immediately after each other.

To wait until a specific time, you can `sleep` for the appropriate amount of time. `sleep` takes a number of seconds as input, and Unix systems traditionally keep and measure time in seconds, so this boils down to simple arithmetic:

1. Convert the wait-for date and time to seconds since epoch.
2. Convert the current time to seconds since epoch.
3. Compute the difference.
4. Sleep for that long.

How to do that is nicely laid out in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646008/486504), but to copy the essential part:

```
current_epoch=$(date +%s)
target_epoch=$(date -d '01/01/2010 12:00' +%s)
sleep_seconds=$(( $target_epoch - $current_epoch ))
sleep $sleep_seconds
```

That particular example is bash syntax, but it should be rather easy to convert to just about any shell scripting language. `$(...)` executes a command and replaces with the output of that command, and `$(( ... ))` evaluates an arithmetic expression.

GNU `date -d` also supports time-only timestamps, so you can say `date -d '05:00'` and it will translate that to the coming 05:00.

Putting this together, it should be easy to make a script like the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no `wait` command. At least not that I know of. Here's my alternative logic:

Create 3 script files for each sas program. These scripts will only execute if the previous sas program has finished execution. This can be done by capturing `pid` of the previous sas program and verifying with `ps` command that it's not running anymore before removing the output files.

Schedule the scripts with `crontab` to be run on every Friday through Sunday, respectively.

So, if I named the first script file `sas_script1.sh`, it would look like this:

```
if [ -f /var/run/sas.pid ]; then
    /bin/ps $( cat /var/run/sas.pid ) >/dev/null
    [ $? ] && exit               #  $? checks the exit status of the last command
fi

rm -f /path/to/file{1..5}.sas7bdat

/usr/bin/sas /path/to/program1.sas &

echo $! >/var/run/sas.pid       #  $! gives you the PID of the last program that's sent background
```

Write the same script for rest of the two sas programs e.g just edit `program1.sas` to `program2.sas`

Create a `file` and write the following in it:

```
00 17 * * 5 /path/to/sas_script1.sh
00 17 * * 6 /path/to/sas_script2.sh
00 17 * * 0 /path/to/sas_script3.sh
```

Now, upload the file as cron job:

```
crontab /path/to/file
```

You can learn more about Un*X this way :D

Comment: *"there is no `wait` command."* `man wait` says otherwise. *wait, waitpid, waitid - wait for process to change state*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - `help wait` will show the help for the bash builtin. You are looking at the kernel system call `wait()`, not the shell's `wait` command.

Comment: @jordanm Argh, you're right. Still, doesn't negate my point.

Comment: For the answerer, I downvoted this because there is a lot of bad practice here. The shell script is messy, likely to lead to stale lockfiles. `[ $? ]` - this does nothing since it's always true, even on a bad return code. It also uses non-POSIX features without specifying which shells it will work in.

Comment: +1 not for the answerer but for @jordanm!

Comment: There is a wait command in shell, but it only works for children of that shell.  Waits for random pids is harder and unreliable. Does your app keep the files open continuously? You could just schedule a rename job 5 minutes after the start. The files will rename but the open stream will remain attached to the inode anyway.